# How do psychoframes work?

Tags: gundam

Exactly what are psychoframes? And what advantages does it give the pilot? We see that units that have a built in psychoframe can drastically increase a pilot's abilities, but exactly what does it do? Amplify your Newtype abilities? Mental connection to the control interface to reduce input lag? I feel that this in particular has been left out quite a bit in terms of the development of the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Psycoframe

> The Psycoframe is a technology that builds on the brainwave-to-machine code translator known  as Psycommu into the atom-level of the metal frame of a Mobile Suit. This allows a Newtype 
>   pilot to control the mobile suit as if it were his/her own body with limitations.

Although not very obvious it seems that Psycoframes allow Newtype pilots to have something like a mental connection to their Mobile Suits allowing them to control them as if they were a part of their body.

Comment: Any particular explanation regarding the last episode of Unicorn? When it got covered in what appeared to be crystalized metal?

Comment: Nope sorry have not watched that episode yet